# How do I detect if a number is a decreasing or increasing number? iOS

Tags: ios, if-statement, sprite-kit

I'm using a SpriteKit game engine within XCode while developing a game that bounces a ball and platforms come from the sky and the objective is to bounce on the platforms to get higher. I need to add a velocity to the ball when it falls down + comes in contact with a platform. I'm having trouble trying to detect the balls Y position. I had something like this in the update method but nothing happens... I'm open to suggestions.

//The value of the _number instance variable is the Y position of the ball.

```
if (_number++) {
    NSLog(@"UP");
}


if (_number--) {
    NSLog(@"DOWN");
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to test for in the 'if' statements?

Answer (score 2):

You can see a node's position by using code like this:

```
if(myNode.position.y > 0)
    NSLog(@"y is greater than 0");
```

If you want to check a node's current speed (vector) you can do it like this:

```
if(myNode.physicsBody.velocity.dy > 0)
    NSLog(@"Moving up");

if(myNode.physicsBody.velocity.dy < 0)
    NSLog(@"Moving down");
```

Remember that position and speed (vector) are not the same thing.

You need to read the [SKPhysicsBody](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/) docs to understand about CGVector and other important issues.

Comment: the second technique worked exactly the way i wanted it to. Thanks so much you're a great help!!

Comment: @ShaunKelly - Happy to hear you got it working. Please check my answer as correct if it fully answered your question.

Comment: unfortunately i'm unable to do that because i don't have enough reputation sorry but i would of if i did

Comment: Did he just say he can't mark your answer correct because of reputation?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, this:

```
if (_number++) {
    NSLog(@"UP");
}


if (_number--) {
    NSLog(@"DOWN");
}
```

doesn't work to do anything. It shouldn't even run. I don't why it doesn't give an error.

number++; is a simplified form of
number = number + 1;

You can't place it in an if statement.

First make the variable @property int ypos in your header.

Then every update compare the current y to the ypos.

After comparing, save the current y to ypos.

Place this in your Update method.

```
if (ball.position.y > _ypos)
{
 //going up
}
else if (ball.position.y < _ypos)
{
 //going down
}
_ypos = ball.position.y;
```

P.S. I haven't had access to a computer so the formatting might suck from my phone